# redux-saga doesn't work, it doesn't catch request actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

I I want to create an application with redux-saga, redux-toolkit. But when I dispatch the action, the saga doesn't catch that action, making it just stop at request. code below:

- package-lock

```
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "antd": "^5.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
```

- store.ts

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({serializableCheck: false}).concat(sagaMiddleware)
})

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

- rootSaga:

```
const rootSaga = function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    authSaga(),
  ]);
}

export default rootSaga;
```

- saga.ts

```
function* loginSaga(action: ReturnType<typeof loginRequest>) {
    try {
      console.log(action);
      const response = yield call(loginApi, action.payload);;
    yield put(loginSuccess("response"));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loginFailure(error));
  }
}

export default function authSaga() {
    return [
        takeEvery(loginRequest, loginSaga)
    ]
}
```

- action.ts

```
export const loginRequest = createAction<LoginPayload>('LOGIN_REQUEST');
export const loginSuccess = createAction('LOGIN_SUCCESS');
export const loginFailure = createAction('LOGIN_FAILURE');
```

I spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and fix it, but it didn't work

I tried many times and checked the ampersands , and ;. But it doesn't work. Saga middleware does not catch actions.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should change your **rootSaga** code from rootSaga.ts into `export default function* rootSaga`
2. In your saga.ts, try to change `export default function authSaga()` into `export function* authSaga()`

Answer (score 0):

I find redux-saga very confusing and hard to use.  Since you are already using redux-toolkit, you can make this a lot easier with [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk).

```
const login = createAsyncThunk(
    'login',
    (payload: LoginPayload) => loginApi(payload)
)
```

To initiate the login process from a component, dispatch the root `login` action with your `LoginPayload`:

```
dispatch(login({ username: 'abc', password: 'xyz' }));
```

The thunk middleware will automatically catch this action, call your API, and dispatch actions for the three stages.

You don't need your three `createAction` calls anymore as the `login` object (a "thunk action creator") also contains [three individual action creators](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#promise-lifecycle-actions) which you can use in your reducers:

- `login.pending`
- `login.fulfilled`
- `login.rejected`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in your `saga.ts` from:

```
export default function authSaga() {
    return [
        takeEvery(loginRequest, loginSaga)
        ]
    }
```

into:

```
export default function* authSaga() {
    yield takeEvery("LOGIN_REQUEST", loginSaga);
    }
```

Sagas are check the dispatched type and hits when it see a type it have to called.